# Efficiently adding elements to a list in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I'm iterating through a list of over three million items and am assigning them integer values. For organization, I have made a dictionary whose keys are the integers and values are the list of items with that score. A priori, I *do not* know how many items will have a certain score, so I'm using the + operator to append onto the list as follows:

```
for e in xs:
   myDict[val(e)] = myDict.get(val,[]) + [e]
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?
2. What's the time complexity of the + operation? Is it creating an entirely new list, copying the elements from the original list, and adding them in?
3. What if I was adding an element to a set?

Comment: Re *"Is it creating an entirely new list, copying the elements from the original list, and adding them in?"*: That would be an example of the [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `append`:

```
for e in xs:
   myDict.setdefault(val(e), []).append(e)
```

This avoids building a new list every time. The operation `list1` + `list2` needs to build a new list in each iteration and hence allocate memory. `append` is more efficient because a list as pre-allocated memory at the end. For example, building a list with append starting from an empty list to a list with 10 million entries takes a bit more than 100 memory allocations.

The [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) method of dictionaries returns the  corresponding value if the key exist. If the key is not in th dictionary, it returns the default. In this case the default is a list. Due to the mutability of lists, we can append to the empty list in the first and to the partially filled list in each subsequent iteration.

An alternative to using `setdefault()` is [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict). Do some profiling to find out which one is faster.

Comment: Aha thank you. So does the setdefault method return the reference to the value of the key then? Otherwise the appending would not do anything.

Comment: Yes. If the key exists, it returns it, otherwise, it sets the key to be the second argument and then returns that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, append and use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for e in xs:
   d[val(e)].append(e)
```

appending is an `0(1)` operation, your approach is linear `0(n+k)` as you create a new list each time.

If you were in a situation where you were adding multiple items, you would `extend` your list.

One thing to note is that `my_list += some_list` is equivalent to `mylist.extend(some_list)`, but it is very different from `my_list = my_list + some_list`. The former adds to the original list, and the latter is doing what your code is doing, concatenating two lists to create a completely new list.

The complexity for  `extend` or `+=` is `0(k)` where k is the length of `some_list`.

[wiki.python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) has a list of the complexity of common operations in Python.

Comment: Is there absolutely no difference between += and extend? That is, can I do += [e] and .extend([e]) and see no differences even on the nanosecond level?

Comment: There will  be nanosecond differences but they both do the same job, I imagine extend may be the very slightly faster operation